# Visual Studio 2019 Short cut Keyboard

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2019 IDE When I load a template to work on .Net Core, Asp.Net or other languages that support Visual Studio 2019 IDE. My Keyboard shortcuts do not work.

Example if I load a basic (Hello World) Web App in ASP.Net Core 3.0 in Visual Studio 2019. If I press F5 to or CTRL F5 to do any debugging it will not work.

Other Shortcut keys CTRL S, K and many others

I try resetting my Keyboard in options and use others options

In Visual Studio 2017 I do not have this problem

Does anyone have this problem?

Comment: It would help if you edited your post to provide a concrete example.  What language your project targets; a specific shortcut key that you modify; the change you make to it _and_ the command(s) you use to make the change; and what happens when you re-open the project.  It would also help if you strung all that together to create a [mre] - create a new empty project, make your change, verify the change has been made successfully, close the project, reopen the project, and verify the change has been undone or modified.  It's a lot of work but it gives people a chance to reproduce your problem.